# How to send object and get array response in volley android?

Tags: android

I need to send object value like

```
{
    "Fromdate":"04/11/2018",
    "Todate":"11/11/2018",
    "Task":"abc"
}
```

I get response in array

```
[{}]
```

Please help for me

Thanks for advance.

Comment: used retrofit 2.0 it is easy and latest for api calling.

Comment: Thank u for answer,i used volley for my  whole project,i need answare in volley

Comment: have you read the volley's documentations

Answer (score 0):

If you could edit your question with a bit more explanation about your problem that would be great for me to help you. But I may know what you need.

Volley waits for a JsonRequest to be queued, but you can actually manage it the way you want, if the response from the server is an JsonArray and you want to send a JsonObject, you may want an approach as follows.

You have to extend JsonRequest and work over the response:

```
private class CustomJsonArrayRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONArray> {
    public CustomJsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener, errorListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, PROTOCOL_CHARSET));
            return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can setup your request:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
try {
    json.put("Fromdate", "04/11/2018");
    json.put("Todate", "11/11/2018");
    json.put("Task", "abc");
} catch( JSONException e){
    Log.e("ErrorBuildingJson", "Error building request JSONObject");
    e.printStackTrace();
    json = null; //GC this
}

//checkConnection is a custom method
if (json != null && checkConnection()) {
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    CustomJsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new CustomJsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, myURI, json,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    if (response != null && response.length() > 0) { //If the response is valid
                        // Do Stuff
                    } else { //If the response is not valid, the request also failed
                        Log.e("ErrorOnRequest", "The server responded correctly, but with an empty array!");
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("ErrorOnResponse", "Response from the server contains errors!");
                }
            }
    );
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(jsonRequest);
}
```

Notice that this approach expects your server to wait for an simple json object and to return an json array as response.

This is a very common approach, and can be found in many repositories, since it gives you  control over the request itself.

Sample: https://github.com/stefankorun/najdisme/blob/master/src/mk/korun/najdismestuvanje/net/CustomJsonArrayRequest.java

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank u for your answer.in my case i used old volley method for get the array response but i cant find the correct solution on the internet.i hope this will help my project ,thank u again.

Comment: For why i ask,i used both different ways,I cant send any data through the get param method and it shows the error when i put  jsonobject in jsonarrayrequest method  but i used without class.so why i ask for the question.i will try this above method,thank u for advance i hope this method will help for me,thank u again

Comment: Sir,this method always return empty array response please help

Comment: This is pretty strange. Could you please post a sample of the returning JSON? Change anything important to a similar invalid thing. Please. Post here or in pastebin.

Comment: My json like this[{"id":1, "userid":1,"credit":500,"debit":"200"}{}{}]

Comment: I get the response from postman but your code is return null response.please help me sir

Comment: Volley super class throw the nullpointerexcption in customjsonarrayreques class?what i have to do?

Comment: That's very unusual. The return from the server is as expected. Could you please let me know where you're getting the nullpointerexception? Which line is generating it?

Comment: Sir,thank u for help.i found the answer sir,my singleton was the problem in my case,i just changed default singleton to custom singleton

Comment: Glad you found your problem man! Hope I've helped at least a bit. Have a great project!